# trying to create a scroll pane for text area

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a scroll pane for my jtextarea.
Below is my code snippet. I wonder why it didn't work. Can someone provide me some insights? Thanks.

```
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(st);
    textArea.setBounds(145, 51, 327, 53);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
    //ScrollPane Code
    JScrollPane areaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    areaScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    areaScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
    panel.add(textArea);
```

Did I miss something? There is no scrollpane appear in my textarea.

Comment: I think you shouldn't set the bounds of the text area explicitly. You might set the preferred and/or minimum size but let the layout manager set the actual bounds that are calculated on those.

Comment: `i wonder why it didnt work` - that's not helpful, please elaborate in what way it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding `textArea` to panel instead of `areaScrollPane`. Try

```
panel.add(areaScrollPane);
```